Changing the default Magento category ID: 2
I am working on a Magento 2 project and need to change the default root category ID, which is currently set to 2, to a different value. I have explored the Magento Admin Panel and database but have not found a straightforward way to change this ID.
Is there a way to change the default root category ID from 2 to another value? If so, what steps should I follow to do this safely without causing issues in the store?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. mentioning that, I am not considering adding another root category.
Many thanks
I tried changing it from the Admin panel: Catelog-> Categories. But there is no options to change Default Root Category ID

I'm afraid that it is impossible to change this id as it might brake many other things.
I would suggest You to create new Category Root by using 'Add Root Category' option visible at Catalog -> Cataegories
Add Root Category Button
Then I would suggest to move all necessary categories from old to new root and set up new Root Category for given store under Stores -> All Stores Root Categeory Assignation For Store
